# Explanation for Exchanges created by NServiceBus with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

[image: Exchanges]

Can anyone please explain why `NServiceBus` creates the above `RabbitMQ` Exchanges along with the expected exchanges based on `Handler` configuration?

Edit: No IEvent / IMessage / object Handler classes defined.
Using DefiningEventAs changes nothing (same exchanges and queues created).

```
                conf.DefiningEventsAs(
                    t => t.Name.EndsWith("Event") && t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"))                    
                .DefiningCommandsAs(
                    t => t.Name.EndsWith("Command") && t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"))
                .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false);
```

Referenced assemblies:

- NServiceBus 4.4.0.0
- NServiceBus.Transports.RabbitMQ 1.1.0.0
- RabbitMQ.Client 3.2.4.0

We downgraded from a later version (though not the latest, I can't recall which one right now) but nothing changed.

Comment: That looks like a bug, what version of NServiceBus.RabbitMQ is this? How does your .DefiningEventsAs look like?(if used)

Comment: Do you have a IHandleMessages<IEvent|object> in your code?

Comment: Question updated (sorry for the delay and thanks for your help, @AndreasÖhlund)

Comment: If you delete the exchanges manually do they reappear when you restart the endpoint?

Comment: Yes. I tried several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is by design, we setup all exchanges including IEvent and Object since there could be subscribers that subscribe to all events using a `IHandleMessages<IEvent|object>` message handler. There is no way for us to know if there are subscribers that has such handlers so therefor we set those exchanges up by default.

They should cause no harm if not used but if you want to get rid of them you canoverride this behavior by implementing your own routing topology, `IRoutingTopology` that ignores those types. You would then register with the transport using [`.UseRoutingTopology<MyRoutingTopology>()`](https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/blob/develop/src/NServiceBus.RabbitMQ/Config/RabbitMqSettingsExtensions.cs#L42)